# enable to access a resource behind 2 zuul proxy with spring cloud oauth2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-oauth2

I' working in an microservices architecture where my ui services are backed by zuul-gui and backend services are backed by a zuul-service proxy (both with Spring cloud oauth2 **@EnableOAuth2Sso** annotation).

My problem is that i'm enable to access backend services after authenticated to gui service with the oauth authorization server. It seems that zuul-gui (the first gui proxy) is not relaying token to zuul-service!!??

I'm wrong when using **@EnableOAuth2Sso** in both zuul proxy? Why is token not relayed between zuul-gui and zuul-service?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: https://github.com/ikane/demo-two-zuul-proxys-oauth2

Answer (score 0):

I finally find a solution to my issue. The idea is to **not secure the 2 second zuul proxy** (zuul-service) and to set **zuul.sensitive-hearder** to empty in order to tell zuul-service to not strip request headers and cookies for the backend service.

Hope it'll help someone else! I struggled and wasted lot of times with this issue!